# form updating fields that haven't been updated by user - PHP Query

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I'm in need of some help with my PHP query. I'm essentially giving users the opportunity to update their own details once they have logged in. The form:

```
<div class="grid-2"> 
    <p><b>UPDATE MY DETAILS</b></p>
        <form action ="includes/update.inc.php" method ="post">
        <label>S.Name</label>
        <input name="update-surname" type="text" placeholder="Enter new surname...">
        <label>Address</label>
        <input name="update-houseno" type="text" placeholder="Enter house no' or name...">
        <input name="update-ln1" type="text" placeholder="1st Line of Address...">
        <input name="update-town" type="text" placeholder="Town...">
        <input name="update-county" type="text" placeholder="County...">
        <input name="update-postcode" type="text" placeholder="Postcode...">
        <label>Contact Number</label>
        <input name="update-number" type="text" placeholder="Contact Number...">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="update-email" type="text" placeholder="Email...">

        <input type="submit" name="update-details" value="Update">
    </form>
</div>
```

My php code which I have currently, if the user doesn't enter anything in the box, it updates the database with a blank input (which I don't want to happen), if there's no input I don't want that field in the table touched.

```
    <?php
// Here we check whether the user got to this page by clicking the proper button.
if (isset($_POST['update-details'])) {

      require 'dbh.inc.php';

// We grab all the data which we passed from the signup form so we can use it later.
    $surname = $_POST['update-surname'];
    $houseno = $_POST['update-houseno'];
    $ln1 = $_POST['update-ln1'];
    $town = $_POST['update-town'];
    $county = $_POST['update-county'];
    $postcode = $_POST['update-postcode'];
    $email = $_POST['update-email'];
    $number = $_POST['update-number'];

      // We validate the updated email is correct if email has been updated. 
  if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: ../after-login.php?error=invalidmail=");
    exit();
    }

    $query = "UPDATE `tblMember` SET `fldSName` = '$surname', `fldTelNum` = '$number', `fld1stLnAddress` = '$houseno', `fld2ndLnAddress` = '$ln1', `fld3rdLnAddress` = '$town', `fldCounty` = '$county', `fldPostcode` = '$postcode', `fldEmailAddress` = '$email' WHERE `tblMember`.`fldMemberID` = 1";


    $result = $conn->query($query) or die ("error");
}
?>
```

Once the php form is loaded, the web page disappears and doesn't stay on the current webpage their on either.

So 2 things needed, help with the correct query and help with the page going blank and not staying on the webpage.

Please note that I know this is vulnerable to injection attack I'm just trying to get it physically working before I attempt to get my head around how I do prepared statements.

Thanks!

Comment: About your second part (so page does not refresh or redirects) you need ajax request.

Comment: Hi @pr1nc3 so the page goes blank and in the URL it does change from `after-login.php` to `update.inc.php`, where abouts in the query would I place a header direct to stay on the `after-login.php` page?

Comment: Just put the header in your page so it knows what to do after submit. You can't put a header inside a query just do it at the end

Comment: You could insert current values with the `value` attribute to the form inputs, instead of putting blank fields. This has the advantage of informing the user about what are the current values and you don't need to change your query. For the blank page, try to do a `header('Location: ../after-login.php')` after a successful update

Comment: @JoseFG His/Her query is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if data input field is non-empty/valid.

**Steps to avoid blank fields update:**

1) Take an empty array

2) Check if every posted variable is valid, if it valid append it to array.

3) Check if the array is not empty.

4) If its not empty, fire SQL.

```
<?php
// Here we check whether the user got to this page by clicking the proper button.
if (isset($_POST['update-details'])) {

      require 'dbh.inc.php';

// We grab all the data which we passed from the signup form so we can use it later.
    $ln1 = $_POST['update-surname'];
    $houseno = $_POST['update-houseno'];
    $ln1 = $_POST['update-ln1'];
    $town = $_POST['update-town'];
    $county = $_POST['update-county'];
    $postcode = $_POST['update-postcode'];
    $email = $_POST['update-email'];
    $number = $_POST['update-number'];

      // We validate the updated email is correct if email has been updated. 
  if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: ../after-login.php?error=invalidmail=");
    exit();
    }

    $update = [];
    if (! empty($surname)) {
        $update['fldSName'] = "fldSName = '".$surname ."'";
    }

    if (! empty($number)) {
        $update['fldTelNum'] = "fldTelNum='".$number ."'";
    }

    if (! empty($houseno)) {
        $update['fld1stLnAddress'] = "fld1stLnAddress='".$houseno ."'";
    }

    if (! empty($ln1)) {
        $update['fld2ndLnAddress'] = "fld2ndLnAddress='".$ln1 ."'";
    }

    if (! empty($town)) {
        $update['fld3rdLnAddress'] = "fld3rdLnAddress='".$town ."'";
    }

    if (! empty($county)) {
        $update['fldCounty'] = "fldCounty='".$county ."'";
    }
    if (! empty($postcode)) {
        $update['fldPostcode'] = "fldPostcode='".$postcode ."'";
    }
    if (! empty($email)) {
        $update['fldEmailAddress'] = "fldEmailAddress='".$email ."'";
    }


    if (! empty($update)) {
        $query = "UPDATE `tblMember` SET ";
        $query .= implode(', ', $update);
        $query .= " WHERE `tblMember`.`fldMemberID` = 1";
        $result = $conn->query($query) or die ("error");
    }
}
?>
```

**NOTE:**

`fldMemberID` seems to be hard-coded.

Comment: Hi @pupil thanks so much for your help. SO again I tried this code in my `update.inc.php` page and it brought me to a new page with the words 'error'. I again tried to delete my first email validation line to see if that would help but no luck. Is there any easy way that I can find out in particular what error it's causing? The reason member id = 1 is hard coded as I'm just doing this to get at least the basics working on my project (I know it should be dependant on who is logged in) but I've not got that far yet :)

Comment: @K.Haydock, I have updated my answer. Can you please check the latest code now. It should work.

Comment: I've just retried your code and placed a header redirect after the last if statement block and works great. However if I don't place any email in at all, it doesn't like it, I think it's my code near the top of the page :'(

Comment: If you don't place an email, your email check that you have before your query will exit the script before anything else happens.

Comment: Hi @pr1nc3, I see, so should I cut and paste that code perhaps below the if statement regarding the email ? :-)Thank you all so much by the way for your help and input!

Comment: I don't see the problem here. I mean if the check of the email fails then you are redirected to the page that you mention in the header and no update happens

Comment: So say as a user, if I only wanted to update my address say. Then no tables update at all and the URL shows my `Location: ../after-login.php?error=invalidmail` redirect. I may just completely delete my line of code. The pain of being a beginner

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
// Here we check whether the user got to this page by clicking the proper button.
if (isset($_POST['update-details'])) {

    require 'dbh.inc.php';

// We grab all the data which we passed from the signup form so we can use it later.
    $surname = $_POST['update-surname'];
    $houseno = $_POST['update-houseno'];
    $ln1 = $_POST['update-ln1'];
    $town = $_POST['update-town'];
    $county = $_POST['update-county'];
    $postcode = $_POST['update-postcode'];
    $email = $_POST['update-email'];
    $number = $_POST['update-number'];

    // We validate the updated email is correct if email has been updated.
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: ../after-login.php?error=invalidmail=");
        exit();
    }

    $query = "UPDATE `tblMember` SET ";
    (!empty($surname))?: $query .= "`fldSName` = '$surname',";
    (!empty($houseno))?: $query .= "`fldTelNum` = '$houseno',";
    (!empty($ln1))?: $query .= "`fld1stLnAddress` = '$ln1',";
    (!empty($town))?: $query .= "`fld2ndLnAddress` = '$town',";
    (!empty($county))?: $query .= "`fld3rdLnAddress` = '$county',";
    (!empty($postcode))?: $query .= "`fldCounty` = '$postcode',";
    (!empty($email))?: $query .= "`fldPostcode` = '$email',";
    (!empty($number))?: $query .= "`fldEmailAddress` = '$number'";



   $query .= " WHERE `tblMember`.`fldMemberID` = 1";


    $result = $conn->query($query);

    header("Location: ../after-login.php");  //make sure of the path

}
```

Basically you are checking your input values and like that you build your query by concatenating the query blocks.

At the end added the header to redirect you to the page you want.

Comment: This can cause SQL syntax error with last comma. Please check it.

Comment: Removed, forgot it while adding new lines. Perfect catch thanks

Comment: You are welcome. How come if user does not post `fldEmailAddress`? The `fldPostcode` will be the last field. Just a curious question. Not doubting about your answer:)

Comment: Then according to the code it will exit in the previous check of the validating email

Comment: Hi @pr1nc3 after removing my first email validation check (which it did not like in there if box left blank) so I tried this code and on the update button click it does redirect me to the same page `after-login.php` however it didn't seem to update any of my tables. I'll have another check now

Comment: The error was in spaces while constructing the query. I made small changes use the current code, updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For first concern you can edit your query as

```
UPDATE tblMember
SET fldSName = IF('$surname' = '', fldSName, '$surname'),
    fldTelNum = IF('$number' = '', fldTelNum, '$number'),
    fld1stLnAddress = IF('$houseno' = '', fld1stLnAddress, '$houseno'),
    fld2ndLnAddress = IF('$ln1' = '', fld2ndLnAddress, '$ln1'),
    fld3rdLnAddress = IF('$town' = '', fld3rdLnAddress, '$town'),
    fldCounty = IF('$county' = '', fldCounty, '$county'),
    fldPostcode = IF('$postcode' = '', fldPostcode, '$postcode'),
    fldEmailAddress = IF('$email' = '', fldEmailAddress, '$email'),
WHERE  
    `tblMember`.`fldMemberID` = 1
```

For Second concern you have to remove die() and redirect to `after-login.php` as

```
 $conn->query($query);
 header("Location: ../after-login.php");
```